# Where are the jquery-mobile button data-icons?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have assumed that if I have the basic setup of...

```
<head>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
</head>
```

then, later in the code if I include, say, a header with a button that uses a 'plus' data-icon...

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="plus" data-role="button">additem</a>
</div>
```

then the buttons would show up with the 'plus' data-icon. The buttons show up, but without the data-icon. What am I missing in my setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link should have `data-role="button"` shouldn't it?

Comment: Take a look at the Network tab in the Chrome developer console to see if the images are failing to load.

Comment: ...but once I added data-role="button" then I could see 404 page errors in the google chrome devtool console and that solved it.

Comment: jquery-mobile was looking for an 'icons-18-white.png file in an images directory under the jquery.mobile.css. I copied it from jquery-mobile/css/themes/default/images and I'm set. <br><br> The Answer is - Put the button data-icons in an images directory under the jquery-mobile.css. (icons-18-white.png has a bunch of typical ones).

Comment: OY - still no data-icons on iphone, fine on chrome browser

Comment: You've changed your question to use the local css file.

Comment: right, now back to http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css and everthing works, chrome and iphone - much thanks

Answer (score 0):

i also faced this prob, but then i tried to add this code into the head. the icon now can be displayed.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
 href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/theme/css/jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
```